# Redirect Add On Domain To Use HTTP Not HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have an issues with an add on domain I have just set up.

My main domain is site wide SSL and I have a .htaccess file set up to force all http request to https and this works fine.

However, the SSL certificate is for the main domain only.

If I try to access myadondomain.co.uk or www.myaddondomain.co.uk it works fine.

The problem occurs (as someone did this by mistake and emailed to let me know) if a user is on a https web site (such as any google search page) if they delete the google.co.uk part and enter myaddondomain.co.uk with out removing the https part web browsers show a warning about potential hacker trying to steal data.

In google chrome you can click advanced and proceed and when you do it shows the content from mymaindomain.co.uk with the address bar showing myaddondomain.co.uk and a crossed out https.

I have read a ton of post on here and all over the internet and as said already had my .htaccess file set up to redirect mymaindomain http requests to https, but for the life of me I cannot get it to send any https requests of myaddondomain to http instead.

Here is my .htaccess file in my main public_html folder...

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect domain and www to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mymaindomain.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mymaindomain.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redirect subdomains to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mymaindomain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mymaindomain.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^wooden-shapes/([A-Za-z-]+) /wooden-shapes.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z-]+) /search.php?cat=$1

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can supply the real web names if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Place this at the very top of your .htaccess file in your top level directory. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Never duplicate:

> RewriteEngine on

Outside of specific Apache config's where mod containers are necessary.
It may vary depending on your hosting conditions, however in Godaddy shared hosting environments & withOUT a Wildcard SSL, ie- a single domain SSL cert., This is the only config that managed to exclude an add-on domain from a force HTTPS redirect:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ADDON_DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]`
# This is *essential* in order to ensure no further conditions are applied after navigating to the add-on domain #
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
# Now that you've defined your exclusion AND made certain its logic is independent from all other URI Requests, Must re-establish this condition once more #
`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`